# Maven YUI Compressor: compress after aggregation

Tags: javascript, maven, yui-compressor

Can I setup Maven YUI Compressor for compression files after aggregation, because I want to exclude "sources" directory, which contain files for aggregation and then compress aggregated files.

For example I have some .js-files inside of **/js/sources/mylib/** and all this files merged into one file **/js/mylib.js** while yui-compressor aggregation stage. In pom.xml I configure yui-compressor to exclude whole **/js/sources/** and compress files only within **/js** library, but yui-compressor execute "compress" goal before aggregation, so I have uncompressed merged files. And I need to fix this somehow

Comment: Did you find a solution for this in the end @SquAreRoot?

Answer (score 1):

Can we turn it around and say: Aggregate after compression? If so, I had the same issue and with the following it worked out for me.

The trick seemed to be to put the output file in the target dir instead of in the source. That way you can include files that got minified in the aggregation.

Files that were already minified I then approach through the basedir var.

```
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>compress</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>        
  <configuration>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>**/*-min.js</exclude>
        <exclude>**/*.min.js</exclude>
        <exclude>**/*.css</exclude>
    </excludes>
    <removeIncluded>false</removeIncluded>
    <jswarn>false</jswarn>
    <aggregations>
        <aggregation>
          <insertNewLine>true</insertNewLine>
          <removeIncluded>false</removeIncluded>
          <includes>
              <!-- these exist only in target dir. the original was json2.js & bootstrap.tabs.js -->
              <include>**/bootstrap-tabs-min.js</include>
              <include>**/json2-min.js</include>
              <!-- use originals for the ones already minified -->
              <include>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/js/backbone-min.js</include>
          </includes>
          <output>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/js/test.js</output>
        </aggregation>
    </aggregations>
  </configuration>
```

Comment: Well, in this case I will not have original unminified files, but I want to keep this files additionally to minified for "developer" user group just for simplifying problem resolving in production. But, well, I think I can just copy unminified files by <copy/> task in Maven from source root

Comment: I think <removeIncluded>false</removeIncluded>
will make sure the originals are kept. BTW, I am currently checking out this plugin, as I am having other bizarre issues with the one above: http://maven-samaxes-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/sites/maven-minify-plugin/minify-mojo.html